# How to populate my DataGridView from an Access database with only selected columns?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
myConnection.Open()
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Products", myConnection)
da.Fill(dt)

datagridview1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
```

Comment: my code above us populating displaying all the data in databse into my datagrid view. but  i want only selected data to display. can anyone help with this?

Comment: You can modify your query to only include the Columns you need. Plus, Columns can be removed from the DataTable. Plus, you can specify in the DGV Designer or in code, which Columns it should display. BTW, you're not using the DataSet, the `OleDbDataAdapter` (don't need to *new* it twice) opens the connection by itself. More important, you need to dispose of those objects if you don't use them anymore. -- The `DataView` (your DataTables's `DefaultView`) has a [RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) property...

Comment: i have no columns in datagrid view becase the datafill from database will include the columns there

Comment: Specify the Fields you need in the query, then. You should do that anyway. Note that the DataGridView allows to hide/show columns at any time, in case this is preferable (maybe because you might need those Columns' values somewhere else).

Comment: can i ask for sample code like hiding the columns sir?how to hide programaticaly>?

Comment: By index: `DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False` or by Column name: `DataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName").Visible = False`

Comment: `select Column1, Column2, Column3 from Products` - Do not load data you aren't going to use

Comment: okay sir thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
myConnection.Open()
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select column-name1, column-name2, column-name3, column- 
name-n from Products", myConnection)
da.Fill(dt)
```

Hi, you can do a select not to all columns else a few columns and in the order that you want. I hope that this was what you were looking for, else only comment. Thank you very much and happy codding. :)